# Probability involving shifts of a sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X=(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $Y=(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be two sequences of i.i.d. random variables on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that $X$ is independent of $Y$. For $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ consider the shift operator $\theta_k$ which maps a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ to $(x_{n+k})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$.
Let the function
$$
f : \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}
$$
be measurable and such that
$$
\theta_k f( X, Y) = f (\theta_k X, \theta_k Y) \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Let $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{Z}}$ be shift-invariant, namely, such that
$$
\theta_k^{-1}(A) = A \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

> Is it true that
> $$
> \mathbb{P}(f(X, \theta_k Y) \in A, \ f (X, Y) \in A) = \mathbb{P} (f(X, Y) \in A) \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}.
> $$

We can write
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(f(X, \theta_k Y) \in A, \ f (X, Y) \in A) &= \mathbb{P}(f(X, \theta_k Y) \in \theta_{-k}^{-1} ( A ), \ f (X, Y) \in A) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(\theta_{-k} f(X, \theta_k Y) \in A, \ f (X, Y) \in A) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(f(\theta_{-k} X, Y) \in A, \ f (X, Y) \in A),
\end{align*}
but is this any helpful? Does one need an additional assumption?